# Array with more than one piece of information - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have this javascript code:

```
var randomwordz = [

{word: 'Sweets', image: 'sweets.jpg'}, 
{word: 'Chocolate', image: 'chocolate.jpg'}, 
{word: 'Snow', image: 'snow.jpg'},
{word: 'Pineapple', image: 'pineapple.gif'},
{word: 'Juice', image: 'j.jpg'},
{word: 'Egg', image: 'egg.gif'},
{word: 'Cheese', image: 'cheese.gif'},
{word: 'Chicken', image: 'chick.jpg'}, 
{word: 'Veg', image: 'veg.gif'}];

randomWords[0].word
randomWords[0].image

randomWords[1].word
randomWords[1].image

randomWords[2].word
randomWords[2].image

randomWords[3].word
randomWords[3].image

randomWords[4].word
randomWords[4].image

randomWords[5].word
randomWords[5].image

randomWords[6].word
randomWords[6].image

randomWords[7].word
randomWords[7].image

randomWords[8].word
randomWords[8].image

var randoms = randomWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomWords.length)];

document.getElementById('randomwords').innerHTML = randoms;
```

My random word is displayed on my page, but ever since I added images to the array when the random word is displayed it shows - [object Object] instead of my random word.

Does anyone know why and how to display just the random word. I need the word and images to be paired for the next part of my code.

Excuse the lack of knowledge I'm new enough to Javascript

Comment: try randomwordz[0]['word'] and randomwordz[0]['image']

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this didn't work sadly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an *Array* of *Objects*, you now need to choose the property you want from the *Object* after selecting an index

```
document.getElementById('randomwords').innerHTML = randoms.word;

// and you may want to do something like this for your image
document.getElementById('randomimages').src= randoms.image;
```